# Ionic Back Button change only title content remains same

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

When I click Back Button it only changes ion-nav-title and ion-content do not get updated to previous one... No error is being showing in console.

Following is my Code.

App.js

```js
angular.module('provisioning', ['ionic', 'provisioning.controllers', 'provisioning.services', 'ui.router'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleLightContent();
    }
  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  // Ionic uses AngularUI Router which uses the concept of states
  // Learn more here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
  // Set up the various states which the app can be in.
  // Each state's controller can be found in controllers.js
  $stateProvider

  // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
    .state('home', {
    url: "/home",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "templates/master.html"
  })

  // Each tab has its own nav history stack:

  .state('home.login', {
    url: '/login',
    views: {
      'home-login': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
        controller: 'login'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('home.operations', {
      url: '/operations',
      views: {
        'home-operations': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/operations.html',
          controller: 'operations'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('home.activate', {
      url: '/operations/activate',
      views: {
        'home-operation-activate': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/activate.html',
          controller: 'activate'
        }
      }
    })

  .state('home.success', {
    url: '/success',
    views: {
      'home-success': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/success.html',
        controller: 'success'
      }
    }
  });

  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home/login');

});
```

Index.html Body Part

```html
<body ng-app="provisioning">
    <!--
      The nav bar that will be updated as we navigate between views.
    -->
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-balanced" align-title="center">
        <ion-nav-back-button>
        </ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <!--
      The views will be rendered in the <ion-nav-view> directive below
      Templates are in the /templates folder (but you could also
      have templates inline in this html file if you'd like).
    -->
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</body>
```

master.html

```html
<ion-nav-view name="home-login"></ion-nav-view>
<ion-nav-view name="home-operations"></ion-nav-view>
```

Login.html

```html
<ion-view>

    <ion-nav-title>
        Login
    </ion-nav-title>
    <ion-content>
        <div class="list list-inset">
            <label class="item item-input">
                <input name="userName" ng-model="userName" placeholder="User Name" type="text" />
             </label> 
            <label class="item item-input">
                <input name="password" ng-model="password" placeholder="Password" type="password" />
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input"> 
                <input name="apiKey" ng-model="apiKey" placeholder="API Key" type="text" />
            </label>
        </div>
        <button class="button button-full button-balanced" ng-click="next()">
            Next
        </button>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: along with upper discription, also when I call first time $location.path('home/operations') it worked but when i go further in views and then call again same command it only update title comes of operations and content remains same

Comment: i am suspecting the issue is directly dependent on route configuration, which you have defined in `app.js`. in order to track down the root cause, live environment is required. so could you create a jsfiddle, and replicate your issue there. http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: My files has many dependencies, Its very difficulty for me to produce it on jsfiddle

Comment: hmm, yeah its difficult to create a jsfiddle. you can refer this plnkr link http://plnkr.co/edit/BZrnKPlCJt93orQp58H3?p=info which demonstrates default tab view, you can update your code and post the link back here

Comment: thanks, Let me create it on this link then i shall get back to you.